# Is it possible to use multiple for loop at same time?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a html form, it have 2 group(Name and fruit), each group have two check boxes, When user clicks the checkbox that input name are user_checkbox[] and fruit_checkbox[] , its will do something,i need to use array and for loop to get the user which group of checkboxes was checked , but it seems not to allow me use multiple for loop.
My Html File

```
//group1
<input name="user_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Peter" onclick="showinputtext();" >Peter
<input name="user_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Billy" onclick="showinputtext();" >Billy
//group2
<input name="fruit_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Apple" onclick="showinputtext();" >Apple
<input name="fruit_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Banner" onclick="showinputtext();" >Banana
```

My Javascript file

```
    function showinputtext() {
    var name = document.getElementsByName("user_checkbox[]");
    var fruit = document.getElementsByName("fruit_checkbox[]");     

      for (var n = 0; n < name.length; n++) && for (var f = 0; f < fruit.length; f++)  { 
    if(name[n].checked && fruit[f].checked){
    dosomething..................
      }
}
```

but it is not work for me, any idea?? thx

Comment: You need nested `for` loops. There are plenty of examples online for this.

Comment: You might consider using a selector: `document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')`.

Comment: does name and fruit same length ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try nested for loops.

```
function showinputtext(){
var name = document.getElementsByName("user_checkbox[]");
var fruit = document.getElementsByName("fruit_checkbox[]"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < fruit.length; j++)  { 
              if(name[i].checked && fruit[j].checked){
                  alert("ok");
              }
         }
    }
};
```

if you use jquery

try it :
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4208n2gq/)

```
$("[type='checkbox']").on("click",function(){
    var name = document.getElementsByName("user_checkbox[]");
    var fruit = document.getElementsByName("fruit_checkbox[]"); 

    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < fruit.length; j++)  { 
              if(name[i].checked && fruit[j].checked){
                  alert("ok");
              }
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `forEach`? Looks a bit nicer and does the same job in this instance:

```
function showInputText() { 
  var nameCheckboxes = document.getElementsByName("user_checkbox[]"); 
  var fruitCheckboxes = document.getElementsByName("fruit_checkbox[]");

nameCheckboxes.forEach(function(nameCheckbox) {
  fruitCheckboxes.forEach(function(fruitCheckbox) {
    if (nameCheckbox.checked && fruitCheckbox.checked) {
      alert ("ok");
    };
  });
});
```

I renamed the variables and the function to make this a bit more readable!

Just remember to change the function calls in the `onclick` attributes if you go for this approach:

```
// Group 1
<input name="user_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Peter" onclick="showInputText();" >Peter 
<input name="user_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Billy" onclick="showInputText();" >Billy

// Group 2
<input name="fruit_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Apple" onclick="showInputText();" >Apple 
<input name="fruit_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="Banner" onclick="showInputText();" >Banana
```

However, reading your post, you might not need to do this at all. It seems unnecessary to iterate through both groups in a nested loop. Why not instead add each item to an array and "Do stuff" with both when the form is submitted?

I would change your checkboxes to have a `fruit-input` and `user-input` class:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="peter" class="user-input">
<input type="checkbox" name="banana" class="fruit-input">
```

Then I would add an event listener to the `fruit-input` and `user-input` elements which listen for changes to the checkboxes. When a change event occurs it then checks if the input has been checked or not, and it will then add or remove from either the `selectedFruits` or `selectedUsers` arrays:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fruit-input")
  .forEach(function(input){ 
    input.addEventListener("change", selectFruit);
});

document.getElementsByClassName("user-input")
  .forEach(function(input){
    input.addEventListener("change", selectUser);
});

var selectedFruits = [];
var selectedUsers = [];

function selectFruit() {
    var fruit = this.getAttribute("name");

    if (this.checked) {
      selectedFuits.push(fruit);
    } else {
      selectedFruits.remove(fruit);
    }
}

function selectUser() {
    var user = this.getAttribute("name");

    if (this.checked) {
      selectedUsers.push(user);
    } else {
      selectedUsers.remove(user);
    }
}
```

Notice how the functions grab the value to add to the arrays from the input element's name attribute. Your current name attributes are invalid as they should really be unique.

It is even possible to refactor my suggestion above to have one generic input field listener and determine the array to add to based on a data attribute or something. But this is a good starting point.

After all this you can do whatever you need with the `selectedFruits` or `selectedUsers` arrays.

Comment: @francoleung - I have just updated my answer to give you a couple options!

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the second for loop inside the first one, like so

```
for (var n = 0; n < name.length; n++) {
    for (var f = 0; f < fruit.length; f++)  { 
        if(chboxsEng_single[n].checked && chboxsEng_fruit[f].checked){
            dosomething..................
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that this will go through every single value of `f` a total of `n` times, which may or may not be behaviour that you desire, it's not clear in the question.